# Graph API: Cannot get "from" field in comment

Tags: facebook, graph

When I used facebooks Graph API til yesterday, it worked to get the "from" field in a comment (API vers. 2.10).

But today it returns an empty field. Does someone maybe knows if they changed something?

The current Version (2.12) also returns nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make this call with a page access token now, not a user access token. More info here https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version2.11#mapi

`/page/* — User information will not be included in GET responses for any objects owned by (on) a Page unless the request is made with a Page access token. This affects all nodes and edges that return data for objects owned by a Page.`

Comment: But as I can see this only works for my own page?

Comment: Yes, each page that wishes to get this information will need to use its own page access token. It seems that FB is essentially cutting down on the information that is available to non-page owners or those looking to scrape data on pages they don't own.