# Facebook Graph API is not returning (From) field for a comment?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments, facebook-graph-api-v2.6

I have a question that recently I am seeing that Facebook graph API is not returning (from) field for a comment.
Ex:- https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/{post_id}/comments?fields=from%2Ccan_like&access_token={access_token} OR,

If you are debugging through graph API explorer then: 
{post_id}/comments?fields=from,can_like

I do not find any documentation on any change from the Facebook side. Please do let me know if I am doing something wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Graph API: Cannot get "from" field in comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48667098/graph-api-cannot-get-from-field-in-comment)

Comment: Try to follow the instructions as mentioned here in the answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76549200/12326605

Answer (score 1):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version2.11#gapi-90

> /page/* — User information will not be included in GET responses for any objects owned by (on) a Page unless the request is made with a Page access token. This affects all nodes and edges that return data for objects owned by a Page.

Answer (score 0):

I have had [this same problem](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/1188939171230605). This happened to me because "my app was in Development mode", even with having all the correct permissions, the **from** field is not returned, this is a behaviour I tested few times.

When I switched my app to Live mode, even though it is not yet approved, the Graph API started to return the **from** field for posts and comments on posts.

If your scenario is similar to mine, then you need to switch your Facebook App into Live mode.

Answer (score 0):

A solution that worked for me: **creating a new app of 'other' kind, not 'business'**

I was first thinking that this was related to facebook permissions but I didn't find anything with that (I asked pages_read_user_content, and it was denied for my 'use case', without telling me if another permission is designed for it). After loosing days with no progress, I discovered that this is occurring only for **businesses** application accounts.

I created a new application using the "other" type, and the from field is available for all comments ! I only needed to put the app in "live" mode!

However I still don't know how to make it work in the business app, if someone know the answer I would appreciate ;-)
I also don't know how much time it may work with the new "other" app