# How to get user from comment on page posts use feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, feed

I got the comments list from the feed, but I could not get their user name and avatar, I used the graph explorer and there were no fields to retrieve the user information that was commented.

I tried, but it does not work.
{page_id}/feed?fields=id,comments{id,message,created_time}

Comment Id also doesn't support getting user information.
448052816017010_448055412683417/?fields=message

// My result

```
    "data": [
      {
        "id": "448052816017010_448055412683417",
        "message": "TYM TYM",
        "created_time": "2019-06-24T07:20:22+0000"
      }
    ] ...
```

Is there a way to get  user or user id, or do I need to grant any permissions?

Answer (score 0):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v3.3/comment

You need to ask for the correct field. `id` is just the id of the comment itself, not the id of the user. `from` would be the correct field. You have to use a Page Token of that Page, and i believe the App has to be live:

```
{page_id}/feed?fields=id,comments{id,message,created_time,from}
```

See this for additional information: [Graph API: Cannot get "from" field in comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48667098/graph-api-cannot-get-from-field-in-comment)

Comment: Thank you for help, I certainly used the page access tooken, and used the "from" field, but this field was not included in the result, is there any other case?

Comment: is your app live? check out some other threads about the issue, there are many stackoverflow threads about it already. i believe you can only get the from field under specific circumstances now, for privacy reasons.

Comment: Thank you again, I did, had a stupid mistake of mine

Comment: what mistake exactly?

Comment: I got the desired fields, just because of javascript. And Luschn, do you have any method to sort the response according (asc, desc) by create_time ({conversation_id}/message?fields=create_time), I'm having trouble with the conversation arrangement.

Comment: you would have to do that on your own, with the `.sort` function of javascript, for example.

Comment: still not sure what you mean with the "mistake". did you solve it? how exactly? i would edit it into my answer, so others can learn something from it.

Comment: sory luschn, I just had a trip so now answer you, I didn't call "from" in FB.api request url, I was absent-minded. but I have found an error, in the data has been return, there are lines with field "from" ("id" and "name") as expected, but there are lines without field "from" there, I deleted the limits in settings page (country, age, etc..) but it still doesn't work

Comment: some users may have disabled the platform, so you cannot get their data

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, I will find a solution to this problem, wish you a great day.

Comment: I'm following FB documentation(https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v8.0/comment) and using Graph API v8.0. I have page access token with required permissions. I am able to get the list of comments but it doesn't show anything for the from field. Any suggestion on this. Thanks

Comment: is your app live and approved by facebook?