# Facebook Graph API not returning "name" and "from" fields for public timeline livestream live_comments end point

Tags: swift, macos, facebook-graph-api

My app is live streaming to Facebook and comments are being fetched by via the URL (endpoint):

```
var urlComponents = URLComponents()
        urlComponents.scheme = "https"
        urlComponents.host = "streaming-graph.facebook.com"
        urlComponents.path = "/\(self.objectID)/live_comments"
        urlComponents.queryItems = [
            URLQueryItem(name: "access_token", value: accessToken),
            URLQueryItem(name: "comment_rate", value: "ten_per_second"),
            URLQueryItem(name: "fields", value: "message,created_time,attachment,from{id,name,picture}")
        ]
```

All comments are being received, however, not all the comments contain all the data fields that were requested.

The `name` and `from` fields do not appear for some users. I have tested the app and found that the missing fields don't appear for users who haven't added the app into their `Business Integration`.

What I tried:

- Read the docu for [live_comments](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/server-sent-events/endpoints/live-comments/) - the documentation does not state that there are any requirements besides the permissions and correct access token.
- Read other SO posts - other questions were solved by adding a page access token because it was not a timeline (destination) issue ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48667098/graph-api-cannot-get-from-field-in-comment),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48732148/facebook-graph-api-is-not-returning-from-field-for-a-comment)) or the Facebook app was in development mode.
- Searched the [Facebook Developer Community Forum](https://developers.facebook.com/community/) - I have found several posts with the same issue without any answers.
- Checked if all required permissions are provided:

> "manage_pages"
> "publish_pages"
> "publish_video"
> "user_videos"
> "publish_to_groups"

- Checked the [Graph API 8.0 version changes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/version8.0/).
- Checked that my stream is public.
- Checked the accounts which commented on my live stream for any privacy settings which would block user data usage.

I have reported this to Facebook as a bug, but I am lead to believe that it's something in my code or understanding of privacy-related changes (some tested streaming apps receive all comments, while others don't).

**EDIT 1 (12.03.2021.):**

It seems like a [Facebook API bug](https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/454010958981233/). The support will assign it to the dev team.